# Which environments support Wingdings?

Tags: css, fonts, browser-support

I'm trying to figure out which environments don't support Wingdings because I'd like to use the font to create icons on my web page.  I need to support IE8 specifically but I'm also concerned with mac.  I can't seem to find a guide anywhere... does anyone know where one is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wingdings fonts are proprietary, and you should not expect to find them outside Windows environments, though they, or some imitations, might exist elsewhere too.

The main reason for not using them is that they are based on a model where glyphs are placed arbitrarily instead of making them reflect *characters*. A document that uses such fonts will have its content completely changed when different fonts are used. So this is a completely wrong way of extending character repertoire. And guaranteed to be unreliable.